# How do I launch MATLAB GUI from a C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, matlab-compiler, matlab-app-designer

I designed a Knob using the MATLAB App Designer, the function accepts an arguments and sets the Knob initial value to it. Now, I want to launch the "knob" from my C# application and pass the initial value as argument from the same C# Application.Is it feasible?

Comment: The answers given by others aren't quite right, you need to [package the app designer app into an exe using the Application Compiler app](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/335101-can-i-transform-the-app-design-matlab2016b-to-executable-form), and then write some kind of script that runs that app after processing command line input, the latter part, I'm not sure how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with MATLAB, but if it's a Windows app, you can launch it running a process.

For example, if the MATLAB app file name is `C:\myapp.exe`, you can run it as follows:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\myapp.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
Process process = new Process();
// Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
process.StartInfo.FileName = "path/to/matlab.exe"; //eg. C:\\abc\matlab.exe
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-n";  //Optional
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();// optional, waits here for the process to exit.
```